# How can i pass variable from one element to another by using VueJs?

Tags: vue.js

How can i pass variable from one element to another by using VueJs ?

[Vue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8ZLM.png)

Comment: Terrible idea. Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because I have two tables.. First table has the ( id = "test1") and second table has the ( id = "test2").. And while I was programming, I needed the variable in the first table to use it in the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var v1, v2;

v1 = new Vue({
    // ...

    methods: [
        changeSomething: function(){
            v2.attribute = 'new value';
        }
    ];
});

v2 = new Vue({/*..*/});

v1.changeSomething();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try it :)